# MVC tabs saving partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using partialviews in each tab.  I have 3 tabs.

After I have selected a tab, how to submit a form in a partialview and have it stay on the same tab after posting to controller?  I just want to refresh the partialview after saving and hopefully not the whole page.

order controller

```
    public ActionResult order()
    {   
        return View();
    }
```

order.cshtml

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Total</a></li>        
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_General_Tab");}
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Partial_Item_Tab");}
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        Content for Tab 3 goes here.<br />          
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
</script>
```

_Partial_General_Tab.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDERMetadata


@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Order"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    // Set New Order Number
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Order_Number, new { @Value = ordernumber })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Order_Date})

     <button id="editorder" type="submit">Save</button>

}
```

_Partial_Item_Tab.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata


@using (Html.BeginForm("Item", "Order"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    // Set New Order Number
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Order_Number, new { @Value = ordernumber })

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Item})

     <button id="edititem" type="submit">Save</button>

}
```

Edit Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ORDERMetadata model)
    {          

        try
        {        

            // update order         

            return RedirectToAction("order");   //<----- Is this correct redirecting?????


        }

    }
```

Item Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Item(ORDER_DETAILSMetadata model)
    {          

        try
        {        

            // update order         

            return RedirectToAction("order");   //<----- Is this correct redirecting, do I need to pass what tab it is on?????


        }

    }
```

Comment: then you have to use Ajax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using Html.BeginForm use Html.AjaxForm